# Angular : check in controller if directives link function is called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So, we have a directive grid, which exposes directive controller to the angular controller, so that controller can call functions on directive (just like a form controller).

Now, in my angular controller every thing works as long as I access the directive controller from a callback action eg. some $scope.xx which are called on some event like click or any thing.

But when i try to access the directive controller at controller initialization time, the directive controller is undefined, that means, directives link function is not called yet.

Here's some code

```
function controller() {
  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.grid.search(xx)
  }

$scope.init() // this will fail, because $scope.grid is undefined.

$scope.onClick = function() {
  $scope.grid.search(xx) // this will work
 }
}
```

is there any other way, other then watching the $scope.grid, to have the $scope.grid.search called on controller initialization

Comment: angular cycle, it will first execute your controller then your generate html as per your controller scope. So in you case you will not have grid object in your controller scope. You should let angular execute one digest cycle before calling $scope.grid.search() . You can use $timeout for that.

Comment: This breaks separation of concerns, in my opinion, when you make assumptions in your controller about an existence of a directive. Granted, tt's indirect here via scope, but it still feels wrong. `$modal` solved that with the use of a service to call functions on the `$modal`

Comment: I still dont understand what you mean by $modal

Comment: why can't you pass a config object to the directive for initialization purposes?

Comment: I honestly don't think this is the way to achieve anything. I don't remember I see anyone use this way, calling function in the directive.  It just feels wrong to me. Maybe you should talk more about why do you want to do it ?

Comment: This is a custom grid which provides ability to get the current selected rows, add new rows to grid, delete rows and much more, the grid has a search box which enables server side search etc. Unless grid expose this api  to controller and unless controller call this functions.. how would the interaction between controller and grid would work (take an example of taking some action on currently selected rows)

Comment: how about using 2 way binding on this grid ? You can have a search attr for this directive and watch it.

Answer (score 2):

You can just broadcast event from `link` function in your directive.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div abc></div>
</div>

myApp.directive('abc', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            $rootScope.$broadcast("initialize");
        }
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.$on("initialize", function(){
        alert("Link function has been initialized!");
    });
}
```

I've created **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10457/)** for you.

Comment: This could be a possible solution.

Comment: This will absolutely work, but doesnt look clean to me, i can change this directive as i have access to it, but if it was a third party directive, this wouldnt be a solution. Looks like i will go with $watch, doesnt look like there's any better solution at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that parent controllers are always called before child controllers.

If you want to run code after your child directive is initialized, you can create a directive and put the initialization code inside of its link function.

This works because parent link functions are always called after child link (and controller) functions.